# Можно ли использовать MVVM там, где нет data binding?

Tags: java, swing, mvvm

На Википедии про [MVVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel) написано:

> MVVM удобно использовать вместо классического MVC и ему подобных в тех случаях, когда в платформе, на которой ведётся разработка, присутствует «связывание данных».

1. Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое связывание данных? В сети совсем
   мало информации. Я могу привести свои догадки на примере Delphi. Там
   можно поместить на форму DBGrid, и данные из базы будут попадать в
   него. То есть, они будут как бы привязаны к нему. Но, если, конечно, в
   настройках правильно все прописать. Это и есть связывание данных?
2. Тогда, как я понимаю, в Java Swing нет никакого data binding. Можно ли там использовать MVVM? В принципе, можно, наверное, просто самому написать функции `bind` и `backBind`, в которых нужные данные туда-сюда передавать?
3. Если можно, то стоит ли? Или лучше MVC или MVP? Понимаю, что так однозначно сказать нельзя, от ситуации, наверное, зависит. У меня десктопный проект с небольшой базой данных (JDBC и MySql), но графический интерфейс довольно объемный и сложный, с большим количеством функций. Предметная область для моего приложения — сложная алгоритмическая задача ([задача о ранце](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5), кому интересно). Подскажите пожалуйста, что в моей ситуации лучше использовать — MVC, MVP или MVVM (опыта ни в чем из этого не имею).

Answer (score 1):

Шаблон MVVM больше ориентирован на технологии .Net  от Microsoft, в частности под язык разметки XAML. 
В WPF или Silverlight привязка данных имеет большое значение, трудно представить серьёзное приложение без механизма привязок (bindings).
Есть альтернатива  на Java - платформа JavaFX.

---

1. Привязка подразумевает взаимодействие двух объектов: источника и приемника. Объект-приемник создает привязку к определенному свойству объекта-источника. В случае модификации объекта-источника, объект-приемник также будет модифицирован (поведение зависит от типа привязки).
   Всего есть 4 типа привязок.

   • **OneWay**: свойство объекта-приемника изменяется после модификации
   свойства объекта-источника.

   • **OneTime**: свойство объекта-приемника устанавливается по свойству
   объекта-источника только один раз. В дальнейшем изменения в источнике
   никак не влияют на объект-приемник.

   • **TwoWay**: оба объекта - применки и источник могут изменять привязанные
   свойства друг друга.

   • **OneWayToSource**: объект-приемник, в котором объявлена привязка,
   меняет объект-источник.

   • **Default**: по умолчанию (если меняется свойство TextBox.Text, то имеет
   значение TwoWay, в остальных случаях OneWay).

**Пример**

```
<StackPanel>
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Height="30" />
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Height="30" Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

2. Самому написать механизм с такой функциональностью будет не просто.
3. Смотрите на платформу JavaFX, если выберите MVVM  и  Java. 
   Если .Net то WPF или универсальные приложения под windows 10.
    Делая Web приложение посоветую Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

На счет какой того какой паттерн использовать я особо ничего сказать не могу. Если нужен красивый, высоконагруженный интерфейс, я бы использовал JavaFX, а там классический паттерн MVC.
А на счет связывания данных, такую фичу я встречал в NetBeans'е (как в старом добром дельфи - "без единной строчки кода"), там есть связывание с помощью своих библиотек (они потом прикрепляются к проекту).

Comment: Фактически это не ответ на вопрос.